# check if email exist in database SQL using codeigniter and AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

[modal screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3d7gr.png)

i have a form inside bootstrap modal, i want to validate if the email already exist in database. the result direct to the blank page with this thing '{"valid":false,"msg":"Email is already taken"}'. i want the msg appear just like i figure it in screenshot.

View

```
    <?php echo form_open('KulinerControl/isEmailExist', 'id="myform"'); ?>
    <div id="msg"> </div>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="input-lg formcontrol"> 
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

JS

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#myform').on('submit', function(e) {
            var email = $('#email').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo base_url()?>KulinerControl/isEmailExist",
                dataType: "json",
                data: "email="+email,                     
                success: function(data){
                    if(data.valid){
                        $('#msg').html(data.msg);
                    }else{
                        $('#msg').html(data.msg);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Controller

```
function isEmailExist(){
$email = $this->input->post('email');
$exists = $this->KulinerModel->isEmailExist($email);
if($exists){
        $msg = array(
        'valid' => false,
        'msg'   => 'Email is already taken');
    }else{
        $msg = array(
        'valid' => true,
        'msg'   => 'Username is available');
    }
    echo json_encode($msg);}
```

update controller

```
function isEmailExist(){
$email = $this->input->post('email');
$exists = $this->KulinerModel->isEmailExist($email);
if($exists){
    echo "Email is already taken !";
}else{
     $data = array(
        'nama' =>  $this->input->post('nama'),
        'email' =>  $email,
        'password' => md5($this->input->post('password'))
    );
 $query = $this->KulinerModel->addMember($data);
 redirect('/KulinerControl/');
     }
 }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: So what is the specific problem or question?

Comment: @charlietfl i want the msg show up just like i attached in screenshot sir

Comment: so, it's a CSS question

Comment: That doesn't explain what the specific problem is in doing it and what is currently happening. Note you need to prevent default browser submit in the submit handler

Comment: @highcal you did fixed your issue ?

Comment: Try console.log(data); as part of the success function, make sure you are getting the expected results. – Also, you are trying to access the variable as if it were an object (data.valid) where you have it declared as an array. So either access it as an array data['valid'], or create the return $msg as an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to stop submitting your form at first then start checking. then if checking find its ok then submit it. i would use the following

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#myform').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();        //<---- stop submiting the forms
        var email = $('#email').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url()?>KulinerControl/isEmailExist",
            dataType: "json",
            data: "email="+email,                     
            success: function(data){
                if(data.valid){
                    $('#msg').html(data.msg);
                    $("#myform").submit();    //<---- submit the forms
                }else{
                    $('#msg').html(data.msg);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: need to add  "$("#myform").unbind("submit");" . but it worked well sir thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think real time email checking is better for your situation

```
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#email').keyup(function(){
            var email = $('#email').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo base_url()?>KulinerControl/isEmailExist",
                data: "email="+email,                     
                success: function(response){
                        $('#msg').html(response);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

In Your controller

```
function isEmailExist()
{
   $email = $this->input->post('email');
   $exists = $this->KulinerModel->isEmailExist($email);
   if($exists){
        echo "Email is already taken";
    }else{
        echo "";
    }

 }
```

To prevent submitting an easy trick

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myform').on('submit', function(e) {
        if ($.trim($("#msg").val()) === "") {
           alert('please choose a different email id');
            return false;
       }
    });
});
```

change Your Form action controller to this

```
function dataInsert()
   {
       $data = array(
        'nama' =>  $this->input->post('nama'),
        'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
        'password' => md5($this->input->post('password'))
       );
       $query = $this->KulinerModel->addMember($data);
       redirect('/KulinerControl/');
  }
```

Comment: thanks for responding sir, your code works good. but it still be able to submitted. is there anyway to prevent submit when the error is on or trigger the function when submitted without refresh/redirect-ing the page ?

Comment: @highcal I edited the answer please try again. comment if not working

Comment: i updated the controller sir, i need to insert the data into database, if error not occured. when using your prevent submitting code it doesn't work well. sorry i dont included it before. thanks

Comment: @highcal since you need to add data into the database, now my controller will not work(ie no data insertion module). My controller is for email verification in real time create another post action controller function. I edited the answer please check.